# ASP.Net MVC Razor Remove Time From DateTime Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, razor

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web application using Razor Views. I have the following ViewModel which is passed to my Razor View and iterated through to display a list of records.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModelLocumEmpList
{
    public IList<FormEmployment> LocumEmploymentList {get; set;}
}
```

**View**

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Employer</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.LocumEmploymentList) {
      <tr>
        <td>@item.employerName</td>
        <td>@item.startDate</td>
      </tr>
      }
      </table>
```

My problem is that the line

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startDate)
```

Returns a date like this **20/06/2012 00:00:00**, and I would like it to remove the time and just display the date, ie, **20/06/2012**.

I have tried adding

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
```

And

```
DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startDate.HasValue ? item.startDate.Value.ToShortDateString(): "")
```

However, they both return the following error message at runtime

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

I have looked at Darin Dimitrov’s answer here [Converting DateTime format using razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor)

However, I don’t have access to the startDate property in my ViewModel, my ViewModel returns an IList of FormEmployment objects which you can see above.

If anyone has any idea’s on how to remove the time from the date time property then I would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks.

Also, my startDate property is Nullable.

**Update**

Based on PinnyM's answer, I added a partial class (see below) to place the [DisplayFormat] attribute on the startDate property.

```
public partial class FormEmployment
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> startDate { get; set; }
}
```

However, my Razor View still displays **20/06/2012 00:00:00** using the following code

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startDate)
```

Any idea's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use  `@item.startDate.Value.ToShortDateString()` (adding the proper validation for null value)

Comment: As I stated in my question, I have already tried using @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
 which results in the same error as stated above.

Comment: Don't use DisplayFor, just set <td>@item.startDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>

Comment: @Pollirata: Cheers, this works. But, can you explain why it works without DisplayFor, and why it doesn't work when I include DisplayFor? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used that on loops before... But I had a similar problem and that's the way I solved it

Comment: The reason is because `DisplayFor` is expecting an Expression lambda which can only be parsed using simple constructs (properties, boolean operators, etc)

Comment: FYI, if the startDate is not nullable, no need the Value and direct @item.startDate.ToShortDateString()

Comment: @V-SHY the question poster specified "Also, my startDate property is Nullable." :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use a DisplayFormat attribute on your model `startDate` property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? startDate { get; set; }
```

The just use `DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startDate)`

Another option is to create a read-only property just for the formatting:

```
public String startDateFormatted { get { return String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", startDate); } }
```

And use `DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startDateFormatted)`

Comment: I can't do this, because my Model Classes are created by a T4 Template, therefore, every time I re-generate the template, my change will be overridden, although, I could maybe create a partial class to hold this single property.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105580/problem-with-dataannotations-in-partial-class and http://ryanhayes.net/blog/data-annotations-for-entity-framework-4-entities-as-an-mvc-model/ for a way to do this using a partial class and metadata class.

Comment: add the attribute ApplyFormatInEditMode to the dataAnnotations of the first solution: [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]

Answer (score 1):

For me I was able to do something similar to the above answer, but using "Value" attribute kept giving errors.

```
<td>
@item.DOB.ToShortDateString()
</td>
```

Other things to note: I'm using ASP.Net Core MVC with the .NET 5 framework so not sure how that's classified or called these days.


Hope this helps someone else coming across this issue later in the future.